# How to fill a matrix with zero (0)

Tags: r, matrix, zero

I need to fill matrix distances with 0. How can I do this?

```
distances <- matrix(1:25, nrow=5, ncol=5)
apply(distances, c(1, 2), function(x) 0)
```

Comment: The first argument to `matrix()` is `data`, so `matrix(data=1:25, ...)` just creates a matrix containing the sequence `1..25`. If you want `data=0`, use 0. Perhaps you copied that example. The `1..25` are not indices. Have a look at the help page `?matrix`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'll just put it here as there are bunch of nice answers in the comments

You could create a whole new matrix using the dimensions of your old matrix

```
matrix(0L, nrow = dim(distances)[1], ncol = dim(distances)[2])  # @nrussell
```

Or, similarly, to save a few keystrokes (because a `matrix` is a special case of two dimensional `array`)

```
array(0L, dim(distances)) # @alexis_laz
```

Or you could preserve the structure of your old matrix using `[]` and fill it with zeroes

```
distances[] <- 0L # @Richard
```

Or you could simply multiply all the values by zero

```
distances*0L # @akrun
```

Or more general solution would be which will take in count `NA` cases too (because every number in power of zero is always equals to 1)

```
distances^0L - 1L # @docendodiscimus
```

Or some of my stuff:
You could convert your matrix to a logical matrix in a various ways and then add zeros, for example:

```
is.na(distances) + 0L # if you don't have `NA` values in your matrix
```

Or just

```
(!distances) + 0L # if you don"t have zeroes in your matrix
```

If you might have zero or `NA` value in the matrix, `row(distances)` (or `col(distances)`) will not:

```
is.na(row(distances)) + 0L
(!row(distances)) + 0L
```

And one can force the entire matrix to be `NA` values, as a way to produce a matrix of `1`'s, then subtract `1`:

```
is.na(distances + NA) - 1L
```

Or just for fun

```
(distances == "Klausos Klausos") + 0L # if you don't have your name as one of the values
```

Another (a bit awkward) method would be using `dim<-`

```
`dim<-`(rep_len(0L, length(distances)), dim(distances))
```

Comment: If you're going to collect all sorts of ways, you can also do `distances^0L - 1L`. Note that this will also convert NAs, if present, to 0s, unlike `distances*0L`.

Comment: @docendodiscimus you are free to contribute, this is a wiki answer.

Answer (score 11):

You could simply enter

```
matrix( rep( 0, len=25), nrow = 5)
```

This should work as wished.

**Edit:** I made a small error (see comment) and have corrected it.